# Xamarin Studio cross platform app error

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

At the moment I'm trying to launch empty app with cross-platform solution in Xamarin Studio.

I've tried make app with empty library project and shared library, both has same errors. Now unresolved problems are:

1) Build error:

```
Error XA5207: Please install package: 'Android Support Library' available in SDK installer. Java library file classes.jar doesn't exist. (XA5207) (*projectName*)

Error XA5207: Please install package: 'Android Support Library' available in SDK installer. Java library file libs/internal_impl-21.0.3.jar doesn't exist. (XA5207) (*projectName*)
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21068646/how-do-i-set-up-teamcity-ci-so-that-it-unpacks-xamarin-components) didn't help me.

2) Some links says it could be because of old `Mono.Android.Support.v4` component. My component version is 21.0.3.0. After clicking for update it says:

```
You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.
```

My `Mono.Android` assembly version is `0.0.0.0` and I dodn't know how to update it.

I've tried PCL project with `PCL 4.5 - profile7`. New projects builds normal, but after first project clean it gives me error about not found `classes.jar` file like described above. Another new PCL project still builds fine.

**UPDATE**

Error in PCL project occures not after clean - it occures with included `Xamarin.Forms` NuGet to Android project.

**UPDATE**

After rising target framework of android project to `v4.0.3` I successfuly updated `Mono.Android.Support.v4` component, but it still show me error about `Please install package`.

**UPDATE**

I'm using Windows 7 OS, same problem with all users including new user. But on another computer with Windows 8 it works. It is not a solution for me, but it can somehow help someone.

Comment: Could you post complete build error?

Comment: All errors messages are here. @Prashant

Comment: Have you tried going into the Android SDK Manager and making sure that the Android Support Library is indeed installed correctly?  It should be under Extras > Android Support Library.  You may have to update your path to point to it.

Comment: `Android Support Library` was re-installed for a several times - that doesn't help. And how to update path? @Yulfy

Comment: @Ircover Assuming your on windows go to your System Environment Variables and append the path to the Support Library to the end of the path variable, seperated by a semi-colon.  It should end up looking like: C:/SomeOtherApp;C:/SomeOtherApp;C:/SomeOtherApp;C:/Your/Path/To/SupportLibraryFolder

Comment: That didn't help too. @Yulfy

Answer (score 1):

i think your java JDK and JRE not install properly and your path not set in your environment variable you must add your jdk path in that and if you are make application using cross platform then also add path SDK in your computer environmental variable. using CMD throw creating project.